# MySQL function dont return select value correctly

Tags: mysql

I have created a mysql function to return value if exist otherwise insert and return the id. My function only work and return id of insert record, but if exist always return 0 (in this case, it should return the id). However, the SQL is working perfectly, when executed outside of function.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GETSTOREID`(offer_id INT(5), affid INT(5), store VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS INT(5)
BEGIN
        DECLARE STOREID INT(5);

        IF EXISTS (SELECT store_id FROM `ccn_stores` WHERE `storeID` = offer_id AND `affiliate_id` = affid)
        THEN
        SET STOREID = (SELECT store_id FROM `ccn_stores` WHERE `storeID` = offer_id AND `affiliate_id` = affid);
    ELSE
        INSERT IGNORE INTO `ccn_stores` (`affiliate_id`, `storeID`, `store_name`) VALUES (affid, offer_id, store);
        SET STOREID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT IGNORE INTO `ccn_store_configuration` (`store_id`) VALUES (STOREID);
    END IF;

        RETURN STOREID;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT store_id FROM `ccn_stores` WHERE `storeID` = offer_id AND `affiliate_id` = affid)
```

does not make sense.

Why are you comparing `StoreId` -- which is `NULL` to anything.  And why are you comparing something that is a store to an offer?

When using variables, I strongly encourage you to use some naming convention so they are not confused with columns.  The stored function could start as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETSTOREID (
    in_offer_id INT(5),
    in_affid INT(5),
    in_store VARCHAR(100)
) RETURNS INT(5)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_STOREID INT(5);
    . . .
```

Comment: Your above suggestion helped me, now its working perfectly. However,  I want to share that i am trying to find if record exist return the id else insert and return the last inserted id. In this case may be the storeId not exist and than else statement can execute (insert).